# NetworkServer.Spawn without activating object

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'd like to spawn an object on the clients without calling `Awake`, so I can send through an RPC to configure it first. Is this possible?

What doesn't work:

- Deactivating the server object before calling `NetworkServer.Spawn`
- Deactivating the prefab
- Deactivating the client object in a `ClientScene.RegisterSpawnHandler` delegate
- Deactivating the client object in the Awake of a -10 priority component (other Awakes are still called)